# App craches with No virtual method isLe2MPhySupported()

Tags: bluetooth

I want to diskcover if a smarphone can handle coded py with the following code.
On a phone witch can handle coded py, it works fine and connects with coded-py.
On a phone tha can't handle coded-py it craches at the line "if(btAdapter.isLeCodedPhySupported())". Can some one help me to solve this problem?

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void startScanning() {
    if(btAdapter.isLeCodedPhySupported()){
        isCodedCapable=true;
        Log.w(TAG, "IsCodedCapable");
    }
    else Log.w(TAG, "Is NOT CodedCapable");
    final ScanSettings settings;
    final List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    if (isCodedCapable) {
        Log.w(TAG, "settingsCoded");
        settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setPhy(ScanSettings.PHY_LE_ALL_SUPPORTED)
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
        .setLegacy(false)
        .build();
    }
    else {
        Log.w(TAG, "settingsLegasy");
        settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
        .build();
}

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btScanner.startScan( filters, settings, leScanCallback);
        }
    });

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopScanning();
        }
    }, 5000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "isLeCodedPhySupported()" is supported from SDK 26, my phone was SDK 23. eddited the code as below. and runs alright now.

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<26)isCodedCapable = false;
    else {
        if (btAdapter.isLeCodedPhySupported()) {
            isCodedCapable = true;
            Log.w(TAG, "IsCodedCapable");
        } else Log.w(TAG, "Is NOT CodedCapable");
    }
```